# Sorting table does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I'm using a plugin called tablesorter. I'm trying to sort a table with rowspan rows. However, it does not sort all columns correctly. Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1731/).

```
<table cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle">AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="expand-child">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Clark</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('table').tablesorter();
```

The age column does not sort properly, how do I make it so that all the columns sort properly?

Comment: For me the demo doesn't sort properly either. The age attributes are sorted as `28->33->8->22` when the order is descending.

Comment: I see the same as @ShanevandenBogaard -- all the sort options work correctly *except* for descending age.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Sort it descending, 33 comes after 28 instead of before. [Maaz figured out why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45195312/157247).

Comment: Ah yes. That's very well spotted :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem (visually, not technically) is that you have a marked `John` as a child of `Peter`. So, only the numbers 28, 18 and 22 are considered for sorting. 33 is never considered for sorting at all.

Changing the first two rows as follows seems to solve the problem

```
<tr>
  <td>Peter</td>
  <td>28</td>
  <td>AAA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>33</td>
</tr>
```

From the looks of your HTML and your sorting requirement, doesn't look like you need the `rowspan` or the `expand-child` class. Maybe you confused `rowspan` with having same values for 2 rows?

Comment: This is a very simple example I made for a bigger issue. I need to have rowspan and I need it sorted accordingly based on the age

Comment: Then, your current example is working fine. You can't expect a child to be sorted along with the parents. The child will stick to it's parent.

Comment: The child should be sorted within its parent though

Comment: Well, that wasn't a part of the question and what I've answered is what I made of _"The age column does not sort properly, how do I make it so that all the columns sort properly?"_. With your current example, there is only one child. If you're going to have multiple children, then maybe edit your question with your exact requirements or ask a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

do you want initial sorting?

sort by age

```
$('table').tablesorter({sortList: [[1,0]]});
```

sort by first name and age

```
$('table').tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]});
```